# Как загрузить картинку в браузер python?

Tags: python, изображения, url, opencv

пишу дискорд-бота, пока он может только кидать кубики. Хочу, чтобы при броске кубиков он кидал картинку с кубиками, на которых будет необходимый результат. Нашёл картинки кубиков в интернете и написал программу с помощью opencv, что будет добавлять на них цифры с результатом. Но как отправить их в дискорд? Я нигде не смог найти загрузку файлов, единственный вариант отправить картинку - embed, но он принимает исключительно url картинки, а не саму картинку. Как автоматически загружать созданную opencv картинку на, например, imgur и получить url этой картинки? В интернете есть уроки, как загрузить с сайта картинку, а как загрузить на сайт нигде нету.
Если требуется, то вот код создания картинки:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
def Draw(result, side):
    title = 'd' + str(side) + '.png'
    if side >= 20:
        img = cv2.imread('d20.png')
    else:
        img = cv2.imread(title)
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX
    size = 4
    match side:
        case 4:
            cord = [185, 180]
            size = 6
        case 6:
            cord = [100, 405]
            size = 10
        case 8:
            cord = [160, 308]
            size = 9
        case 10:
            cord = [145, 236]
            size = 5
        case 12:
            cord = [120, 305]
            size = 6
        case 20:
            cord = [165, 300]
    if side > 20:
        cord = [165, 300]
    res = result[0]
    cv2.putText(img, str(res), cord, font, size, color=(0, 0, 0), thickness = 20)
    return img
```

Он, вместе с кодом самого бота и картинками есть на github - https://github.com/postopython/Novirbot

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл модуль imgur, всё сделал через него.